# How to run selenium test by using Pyqt5?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyqt5

I have start and stop buttons and when I click on the start button the selenium test runs and click on stop button the test stops.
But now when I click on the start button test runs but the app is stacking. You can see screen of error by the link.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yxJh.png)

in the Main.py is written pyqt5 code and in the test_***.py is written test with selenium.

*Also how can I stop the loop by clicking on button?

**Main.py**

```
class DepositPage(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(DepositPage, self).__init__()
    self.ui_table = UiMainWindow()
    self.ui_table.setupUi(self)
    self.ui_table.back_button.clicked.connect(self.back_main_page)
    self.process = True
    self.ui_table.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.start_process)
    self.ui_table.pushButton_2.pressed.connect(self.stop_process)

def start_process(self):
    self.ui_table.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
    self.ui_table.back_button.setEnabled(False)
    self.ui_table.pushButton.setStyleSheet('background-color:#9c9c9c')
    self.ui_table.back_button.setStyleSheet('background-color:#9c9c9c')
    while self.process == True:
        deposit_data = DataDepositPage(1)
        # QApplication.processEvents()
        deposit_data.open_page()
        deposit_data.select_state()
        print("Process...")
        time.sleep(3)

def stop_process(self):
    self.ui_table.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)
    self.ui_table.back_button.setEnabled(True)
    QApplication.processEvents()
    self.process = False
    deposit_data = DataDepositPage(1)
    deposit_data.close_browser()
```

**test_***.py**

```
class DataDepositPage(Browser):
USERNAME = '[name="Input_rcqgkgxt"]'
PASSWORD = '[placeholder="Password"]'
USER_PROFILE = '[class="bc-dropdown-container"]:first-child'
LOGIN_BUTTON = '[class="sign-in-page-form-btn ng-binding"]'
STATE_BUTTON = '[class="form-control multi-select-input ng-binding"]'
STATES = '[class="items-list-container"] li'
APPLY_BUTTON = '[data-i18n="_Apply_"]'
ROW = 'tbody > tr:first-of-type'
COLUMNS = '//*[@id="betTableCnt"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[@sortable="RequestTimeLocal" or @sortable="ClientLogin" or @sortable="ClientName" or sortable="Amount" or @sortable="ClientBankName" or @sortable="IBAN"]'
ITEMS = '[ng-mousedown="navigate($event,submenulvl1)"]'
CLOSE_AD = '[id="nextButtonBC-23d-dcd-234-f54-54v"]'
data_csv = pd.read_csv("./deposit_data.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["Status", "ClientName", "ClientLogin", "Amount", "RequestTime", "ClientBankName", "IBAN"])

def __init__(self, headless):
    super(DataDepositPage, self).__init__(headless)

def open_page(self):
    self.driver.get("https://backoffice.betcoapps.com/login.html#/")

def select_state(self):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.STATE_BUTTON))
        )
        state_button = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.STATE_BUTTON)
        state_button[0].click()
        state_list = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.STATES)
        state_list[3].click()
        ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
        apply_button = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.APPLY_BUTTON)
        apply_button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, self.ROW))
            )
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.COLUMNS))
            )
            rows = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, self.ROW)
            match = False
            for row in range(len(rows) - 1):
                columns = rows[row].find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.COLUMNS)
                array = []
                for column in columns:
                    array.append(column.text)
                for data in self.data_csv.values:
                    for el in range(len(data) - 1):
                        if array[el] == data[el + 1]:
                            match = True
                if match == False:
                    self.df.loc[len(self.df.index)] = ['a'] + array
                    self.df.to_csv("./deposit_data.csv", index=False)
        except:
            self.driver.close()
            self.display.stop()

def close_browser(self):
    self.driver.close()
    self.display.stop()
```

Comment: The error exactly says what you're doing: you're *blocking* the interface, due to that `while True:` loop. Use QThread and custom signals instead.

Comment: Could you please send example?

Answer (score 0):

you should use a thread like this :

in **Main.py** :

```
import threading 

def thread(x) : # add parameters(x) that you wanna send to test.py class 
     t = threading.Thread(target=e, args=(x,)) 
     # e is the name of the function that you wanna run in test_.py 
     # x are parameters if you need them
     t.start()
     # start process
```

in *start_process* function

```
while t.is_alive() :
    QApplication.processEvents() # to keep GUI updated
```

I hope that helps .